# I get the 404 error after migrating the window server

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

We are migrating the old server to the new server. The new product is on Windows server 2016.

All settings have been completed. However, when I tried to enter the website,

The 404 error resource was not found.

For example, the website name will be similar to the server name, but I can use a bad link to access the website, but not the actual link.

Edit:

The old version of Windows was 2008, the actual link is mydomain.com/applicationname/test.aspx, the bad link is mydomain.com/test.aspx.

Comment: 1) What's the old server's Windows version? 2) What kind of URLs work and what fail? 3) What does FRT say about those 404 errors? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: @sdrfgd It is not possible to confirm your problem based on the information you posted, please post detailed information about your problem. or you can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question. hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether you are publishing applicationname or virtual directory. and do you use url rewriting in your webiste?

I suggest you use failed request tracking to view 404 error information.

[Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85).